# Guidance on Algorithmic Thinking (4 fours equation)

Tags: algorithm, computation-theory

I recently saw a logic/math problem called 4 Fours where you need to use 4 fours and a range of operators to create equations that equal to all the integers 0 to N.

How would you go about writing an elegant algorithm to come up with say the first 100...

I started by creating base calculations like 4-4, 4+4, 4x4, 4/4, 4!, Sqrt 4 and made these values integers.

However, I realized that this was going to be a brute force method testing the combinations to see if they equal, 0 then 1, then 2, then 3 etc...

I then thought of finding all possible combinations of the above values, checking that the result was less than 100 and filling an array and then sorting it...again inefficient because it may find 1000s of numbers over 100

Any help on how to approach a problem like this would be helpful...not actual code...but how to think through this problem

Thanks!!

Comment: 4/4, (4+4)/4, (4+4+4)/4...

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - you only have the digit "4" 4 times...

Comment: I.E. I can only user digit 4 max 4 times? Can I use 3 4s or 2 4s?

Comment: AFAIK, you have to use it 4 times. A solution for the first 100 is here - http://mathforum.org/ruth/four4s.puzzle.html, but that doesn't actually answer the question

Comment: Please list all of the allowed operators / symbols.

Comment: We had a similar puzzle in Primary school - given the numbers 1,2,3,4, use all four to create expressions evaluating to 1..100. Seem to remember 89 and 90 were hard.

Comment: O(n) solution:

Start with `(4*4)/(4*4) = 1` and apply `++` operator as many times as required :-P

Comment: nice one Rob :) Thanks everybody, Rob got it
@mbeckish - I dont recall seeing a list of allowed operators but the basics +, -, /, *, !, sqrt, ( ) can get you quite far as I was able to do the first 30 in about 10 minutes on paper...but could not figure out how to construct an algorithm (ie the thought process)

Comment: @Rob are you sure ++ is allowed? AFAIK, this problem was originally intended for solving on paper, and ++ doesn't work outside computer languages, it translates to "+1", so it shouldnt be used, right?

Comment: @Tejash - my comment was tongue in cheek. I'm sure ++ is not in the spirit of the original challenge.

Comment: @Rob haha, good one :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. There are a couple of different things going on here. One issue is how to describe the sequence of operations and operands that go into an arithmetic expression. Using parentheses to establish order of operations is quite messy, so instead I suggest thinking of an expression as a stack of operations and operands, like `- 4 4` for 4-4, `+ 4 * 4 4` for (4*4)+4, `* 4 + 4 4` for (4+4)*4, etc. It's like Reverse Polish Notation on an HP calculator. Then you don't have to worry about parentheses, having the data structure for expressions will help below when we build up larger and larger expressions.

Now we turn to the algorithm for building expressions. Dynamic programming doesn't work in this situation, in my opinion, because (for example) to construct some numbers in the range from 0 to 100 you might have to go outside of that range temporarily.

A better way to conceptualize the problem, I think, is as breadth first search (BFS) on a graph. Technically, the graph would be infinite (all positive integers, or all integers, or all rational numbers, depending on how elaborate you want to get) but at any time you'd only have a finite portion of the graph. A sparse graph data structure would be appropriate.

Each node (number) on the graph would have a weight associated with it, the minimum number of 4's needed to reach that node, and also the expression which achieves that result. Initially, you would start with just the node (4), with the number 1 associated with it (it takes one 4 to make 4) and the simple expression "4". You can also throw in (44) with weight 2, (444) with weight 3, and (4444) with weight 4.

To build up larger expressions, apply all the different operations you have to those initial node. For example, unary negation, factorial, square root; binary operations like `* 4` at the bottom of your stack for multiply by 4, `+ 4`, `- 4`, `/ 4`, `^ 4` for exponentiation, and also `+ 44`, etc. The weight of an operation is the number of 4s required for that operation; unary operations would have weight 0, `+ 4` would have weight 1, `* 44` would have weight 2, etc. You would add the weight of the operation to the weight of the node on which it operates to get a new weight, so for example `+ 4` acting on node (44) with weight 2 and expression "44" would result in a new node (48) with weight 3 and expression "+ 4 44". If the result for 48 has better weight than the existing result for 48, substitute that new node for (48).

You will have to use some sense when applying functions. factorial(4444) would be a very large number; it would be wise to set a domain for your factorial function which would prevent the result from getting too big or going out of bounds. The same with functions like / 4; if you don't want to deal with fractions, say that non-multiples of 4 are outside of the domain of / 4 and don't apply the operator in that case.

The resulting algorithm is very much like Dijkstra's algorithm for calculating distance in a graph, though not exactly the same.

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation of how to tackle such a problem...although most of it was way over my head :) I do appreciate your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the brute force solution here is the only way to go.
The reasoning behind this is that each number has a different way to get to it, and getting to a certain `x` might have nothing to do with getting to `x+1`.

Having said that, you might be able to make the brute force solution a bit quicker by using obvious moves where possible.
For instance, if I got to 20 using "4" three times (`4*4+4`), it is obvious to get to 16, 24 and 80. Holding an array of 100 bits and marking the numbers reached

Comment: I think that seems like the only option...but you have to use all 4's...but I think your array idea should help as you would be adding more and more numbers in the array and you would not have to recalculate

Answer (score 1):

Similar to subset sum problem, it can be solved using [Dynamic Programming (DP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) by following the recursive formulas:

```
D(0,0) = true
D(x,0) = false     x!=0
D(x,i) = D(x-4,i-1) OR D(x+4,i-1) OR D(x*4,i-1) OR D(x/4,i-1)
```

By computing the above using DP technique, it is easy to find out which numbers can be produced using these 4's, and by walking back the solution, you can find out how each number was built.

The advantage of this method (when implemented with DP) is you do not recalculate multiple values more than once. I am not sure it will actually be effective for 4 4's, but I believe theoretically it could be a significant improvement for a less restricted generalization of this problem.

Comment: This might not work if parentheses are allowed, because you can't always build the expression by including one more 4 at a time.  For example, how would DP get from `4 + sqrt(4)` to `4 + sqrt(4*4)`?

Comment: @mbeckish - you wouldn't. You'd go from 'sqrt(4*4)' to '4 + sqrt(4*4)'

Comment: @amit NB there are far more than 4 choices for going from `i-1` to `i`. Also, you can add operators to an expression without adding any more 4's. Not sure how this loop should be incorporated. E.g. use one 4 to get 5 by applying several operators: `Ceil(Sqrt(4!)) = 5`

Comment: @Rob - Yes, that was a poor example.  But the point is, when you have parentheses, you can't always build an expression one digit at a time.  Maybe with the additional restriction of only having four 4's as digits you can work around this, but it is not clear that it is always possible.

Comment: @Rob - the idea I believe is that you are to use basic operators and not programming functions like Ceil....so ( ) / * + - sqrt !

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just an extension of Amit's. 
Essentially, your operations are:

1. Apply a unary operator to an existing expression to get a new expression (this does not use any additional 4s)
2. Apply a binary operator to two existing expressions to get a new expression (the new expression has number of 4s equal to the sum of the two input expressions)

For each `n` from 1..4, calculate `Expressions(n)` - a List of (Expression, Value) pairs as follows: 
(For a fixed `n`, only store 1 expression in the list that evaluates to any given value)

1. Initialise the list with the concatenation of `n` 4s (i.e. 4, 44, 444, 4444)
2. For `i` from 1 to `n-1`, and each permitted binary operator `op`, add an expression (and value) `e1 op e2` where `e1` is in `Expressions(i)` and `e2` is in `Expressions(n-i)`
3. Repeatedly apply unary operators to the expressions/values calculated so far in steps 1-3. When to stop (applying 3 recursively) is a little vague, certainly stop if an iteration produces no new values. Potentially limit the magnitude of the values you allow, or the size of the expressions.

Example unary operators are `!`, `Sqrt`, `-`, etc. Example binary operators are `+-*/^` etc. You can easily extend this approach to operators with more arguments if permitted.

You could do something a bit cleverer in terms of step 3 never ending for any given `n`. The simple way (described above) does not start calculating `Expressions(i)` until `Expressions(j)` is complete for all `j < i`. This requires that we know when to stop. The alternative is to build Expressions of a certain maximum length for each `n`, then if you need to (because you haven't found certain values), extend the maximum length in an outer loop.